# DDE - Can not add interfaces for Java Class design element

Tags: xpages

I would like to add some interfaces to a Java CLass design element. But when I start typing in the Implement Interfaces Selection dialog the "Searching indicator" stays at 0%. How can I fix this?

Comment: Typically when I see that behavior, restarting Designer (and Notes) resolves it.

Comment: In what perspective? I recommend to use Java perspective.